# ¿Leer una base de datos con Entity Framework con permisos Solo de Lectura?

Tags: oracle, code-first

Estoy realizando un webservice utilizando un proyecto WCF y EF6 Code First y DB Firts, sin embargo los permisos que tengo sobre una base de datos Oracle son de solo lectura, ¿existe alguna manera de papear esa BD con entity?, ya que para saber las restricciones de cada columna de alguna tabla se necesita tener aun mas privilegios sobre la BD.